# how to skip displaying a row in a table,created using display:table tag, in JSP

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am using strut2-JSP to generate a report.In that report I am trying to skip displaying some rows in the table that has a specific "groupName" but need to include the information of that row while calculating the total in the column or in the row. ![My report roughly looks like the table below][1]

**Group Name                             |Net Total**
Multi_species category               | $300
Multi_species category               | $400
Multi_species category Subtotal | $700

***But I have to display it as below:***

**Group Name                             |Net Total**
Multi_species category Subtotal | $700

For example:I am trying to get rid of the row that has group name "Multi_species category" but like to keep the rows ("Multi_species category subTotal") that calculating totals. Tried with an "if" condition inside the table that did not work . Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Here is my example code to generate this table :

```
<display:table id="reportTable"
                   name="tableData"
                   requestURI=""
                   cellspacing="0px"
                   export="true"
                   class="displaytagTable">

        <display:setProperty name="decorator.media.pdf"
                             value="expenditures.decorator.ItextTotalSpeciesDecorator"/>


        <c:if test="${ !( groupName == \"Multi_species category\") }">

            <display:column title="Group Name" property="groupName" group="1"/>

            <display:column title="Net Total" property="total" class="alignRight"
                            decorator="expenditures.decorator.DollarDecorator"
                            total="true"/>

        </c:if>

</display:table>
```

Please let me know if more information is required.
Thanks in advance

**Additionally, I am getting error at the line :**

```
<c:if test="${ !( groupName == \"Multi_species category\") }">
```

- how should I compare string here?

Comment: Don't know about JSTL but if you use s:if groupName is a String then using == probably isn't what you want use groupName.equals('Multi_species category') or equalsIgnoreCase.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do this in your action, so that only the rows you want displayed are passed to the DisplayTag

Comment: What type is your `groupName`?

Comment: If I do it from action , I have to calculate the totals there, For a list of thousands different types of group and thousands of items in each group, it is not a convenient option for us.

Comment: This should work `<s:if test="groupName != 'Multi_species category'">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue by adding a class to every column in that specific row and removed the parent of the columns. here is the link for the example:

[How to remove a row from a table using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807316/how-to-remove-a-row-from-a-table-using-jquery/13807571#13807571)

Thanks for trying to help me though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<s:if test="!groupName.equals('Multi_species category')">
   Expression True
</s:if>
<s:else>
   Expression False
</s:else>
```

Comment: **I finally resolved this issue by adding a class to every column in that row and removed the parent of those columns using Javascript.**