# How to remove a row from a table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

I have a table that has just one row that has columns with class='99999'.( Other rows have columns with different classes and there is no way I could set an id for a row as this table is generated by display:table ). I am trying to delete the whole row that has columns with class='99999'. Looks like the part:

```
$("td.99999").first().parent().remove();
```

is not working.

Here is the html looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert("I am here");
        $("td.99999").first().parent().remove();
    });
</script>
</head>

<table border="1">
    <tr >
        <th>category</th>
        <th>rank</th>
        <th>priority</th>
        <th>contact</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>tax</th>
        <th>total price</th>
        <th>shipping</th>
        <th>Net payment</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="displaytagOddRow">
        <td class="99999">category 1</td>
        <td class="99999">99999</td>
        <td class="99999">something</td>
        <td class="99999">something</td>
        <td class="99999 alignRight">$3,433</td>
        <td class="99999 alignRight">$300</td>
        <td class="99999 alignRight">$3,733</td>
        <td class="99999 alignRight">$349</td>
        <td class="99999 alignRight">$4,082</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="displaytagOddRow">
        <td class="3333">category 2</td>
        <td class="3333">3333</td>
        <td class="3333">something</td>
        <td class="3333">something</td>
        <td class="3333 alignRight">$3,433</td>
        <td class="3333 alignRight">$300</td>
        <td class="3333 alignRight">$3,733</td>
        <td class="3333 alignRight">$349</td>
        <td class="3333 alignRight">$4,082</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console? Your code works just fine for me, so your problem is elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/Ch6MM/ Perhaps you should consider using a newer version of jQuery. v1.3.2 is **very** old.

Comment: Seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/2Gf8a/ Maybe this is a problem with jQuery 1.3 - try to use a newer version. Maybe this solves it.

Comment: Just a thought: wouldn't it be easier to store the ID in the table row instead of every cell within that row?

Comment: **You guys are right. I needed to upgrade jquery version to 1.4. It's working now. Thank you all for helping me and for the link of jsfiddle.**

Comment: i don't recommend using the class selector for this purpose, i.e. the given answer below. supose in some point you add a dom element with the same class on top of the table. the behaviour of the code would be messy. use id instead for better scalability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added the reference to the jquery file in the script tag and in the same tag you are writing the code.You will have to put it in another script tag as below:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){

                                         alert("I am here");
                 $("td.99999").first().parent().remove();


                                      });
     </script>
```

Keep your below code as

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.3.2/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

It will work fine...

Comment: **Additionally : upgrade jquery version to 1.4.**